# Hide an image inside a link based on attribute selector with CSS

Tags: html, css

This is the markup:

```
<p> 
  <a href="http://www.domain.com/stack-2015-overflow-648198/">
  <img src="link to image"> 
   See also: Stack 2015 and Overflow Review </a>
</p>
```

The content is loaded by AJAX but I think it should still be styled with CSS. Here is my CSS:

```
a[href*="www.domain.com"] img { display: none; }
```

but it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Show more about your ajax part, since it really works by now.

Comment: What does this have to do with the AJAX part?

Comment: But your example can not actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: The issue you describe ("does not work" needs to be clarified, though) cannot be recreated using the code you have provided.

Comment: @YinGang and Shaggy I will add more details soon.

Answer (score -2):

I've been using CSS for a long time, and I've never seen anything like that. You should apply a class or ID to the anchor tag and then reference it as:

```
#anchorId>img {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: I can't add a `id` to it Christian

Comment: then if you're not supporting pre-HTML5 browsers, you can use a pseudo class of :first-of-type, depending on what other markup is on your page. If that was you're only markup, you can simply use p>a>img {}. But without an ID or class to specify the p or a element, there's not much else you can do with pure CSS.